# Modified minimum coin change

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, puzzle

Suppose you have a **K** dollars Bill.
Given 4 coins of value {1,4,6,9}
Find the minimum number of coins the sum of which is K, when K is represented in Binary, meaning input's length is log(K)

I've tried Dynamic programming, but i didn't figure it out.
Does anybody has any idea of how to start solving that ?
It's related to knapsack problem somehow but i can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: convert K into decimal and apply dp . what's the problem ?

Comment: @aseem K is exponential in the input size, and I assume OP doesn't want an exponential algorithm

Comment: what complexity do you require ?

Comment: can the same coin used many times ? It seems to be true , but please mention it .

Comment: @Jay M: if you like one of the answers, could you accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about checking the number of coins as a function of K%9? Then you can translate it to the function of log(K).

Let K%9 = r, i.e. there is an integer n such that K = 9n + r, and r is between 0 and 8 inclusive.

- r=0: we need **n coins** of value 9,
- r=1: we need n coins of value 9 + 1 coin of value 1 = **n+1 coins**
- r=2:    we need n coins of value 9 + 2 coins of value 1 = **n+2 coins**
- r=3: we need (n-1) coins of value 9 + 2 coins of value 6 = **n+1 coin**, **or 3 coins** of value 1 if K=3
- r=4: we need n coins of value 9 + 1 coin of value 4 = **n+1 coins**
- r=5: we need n coins of value 9 + 1 coin of value 4 + 1 coin of value 1 = **n+2 coins**
- r=6: we need n coins of value 9 + 1 coin of value 6 = **n+1 coins**
- r=7: we need n coins of value 9 + 1 coin of value 6 + 1 coin of value 1 = **n+2 coins**
- r=8: we need n coins of value 9 + 2 coins of value 4 =
  **n+2 coins**

Proofs:
For the case **r=0**: we know that we can do it with n coins. If we were using m coins, m < n, than the max total value is m * 9, 9 being the max value of the coin. But 9m is less than K=9n, so we cannot use m coins to get K

For the cases where we have **r=1, r=3, r=4 and r=6**: following the same reasoning as above, we know that n coins would be enough (9n < K, K being 9n +r), and we know how to do it with n+1 coins.

For the cases **r=2, r=5 and r=8** For the total amount, K, K%3=(9n+r)%3=r%3=2; for the values of the coins, 6%3=0 and 9%3=0, but 1%3=1 and 4%3=1. Therefore, to get K we need at (2+3j) coins of values 1 or 4. Now we need to prove that, if we use n+1 coins, and at least 2 coins are of values 1 or 4, we cannot get K. Indeed, the max value of n+1 coins is 9*(n-1) + 2*4 = 9n-1, this is less than K=9n+r.

Finally, for the case **r=7**: Suppose we use n+1 coin. All of them is 9, we get 9*(n+1), this is not we want. If at least one of them is not 9, than the total value is at most 9n + 6, 6 being the second most valuable coins, this is not enough. Thus, n+1 is not enough. And we know how to get it with n+2. Voila!

Comment: is there anyway to prove all these cases together using induction ?
if not can you please prove one of the cases.. thanks

Comment: I do not think there is a simpler solution. But you can categorize the cases as I suggest above.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical dynamic program for this problem loops j from 0 to K, computing each time the minimum number of coins to make change for a j-dollar bill. When j = 0, zero coins is optimal. For each other j, the answer is one coin plus the minimum for j - 1, j - 4, j - 6, or j - 9 (when those quantities are nonnegative). For other sets of denominations, replace 1, 4, 6, 9 appropriately.

To derive a table as Yulia V did, one can show that, for every set of denominations, when K is sufficiently large, optimal change includes a coin of largest denomination. Loop j up from 0, looking for exceptions, where an exception is when it takes more coins to make j - 9 dollars than j (or when j - 9 is negative). After 9 non-exceptions in a row, there can be no more exceptions. (For other sets of denominations, substitute the largest denomination for 9 in the foregoing text.)

Comment: Are you describing a general approach here or one specific to the instance at hand? I have to say I'm having a hard time understanding this answer, can you maybe clarify the second paragraph?

Comment: @NiklasB. General approach, but trying not to overload the math notation (apparently unsuccessfully).

Comment: Let's say d is the largest denomination. So what you're saying is I just do a normal DP and find the smallest i such that f(i - d + 1) = f(i - d + 1), ..., f(i) = f(i - d) and then for all j > i we have f(j) = f(j - floor((j-i)/d)*d) + floor((j-i)/d)? Is there a useful upper bound for i?

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, the bound on `i` should be polynomial in `d`. Assuming that there is a penny, the optimum for `K >= d` including at least one `d` coin is at most `K/d + d - 1` coins, whereas if we use coins of denomination `d - 1` or less, the optimum is at least `K/(d - 1) = K/d + K/(d (d - 1))`. If `K >= d (d - 1)^2`, then the former is no worse.

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't see any obstacle to the proof for the penniless case, but it looks complicated and not in an interesting way.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming on K mod 36, then use 9s for the rest, where 36 = lcm(1, 4, 6, 9).